# How to undo forced stop app in Android

Tags: force-stop

how do I undo a forced stop for google play services.  I tried rebooting but it did not clear the forced stop.

Comment: You can't. Google Play Services will be rerun when it's needed, you don't/can't manually run it.... or, did you mean the "Force stop" button is disabled? You can't manually force stop this service either.